# SQL return having sum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that checks a group and makes sure that it has more than 1 value under 2

```
SELECT `tile` FROM TFResults
GROUP BY `tile`
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN `Place` < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)> 1 ;
```

I would like to return the value of sum also but can't seem to get it to work

```
SELECT `tile`, thesum
FROM TFResults
GROUP BY `tile`
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN `Place` < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as thesum > 1 ;
```

Comment: Do it the other way, have the case in the select list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to move sum part to select statement. And if you need only one column to check then use if instead CASE. Check Below

```
SELECT tile, SUM(if(Place < 2, 1, 0)) place_sum 
FROM TFResults
GROUP BY tile
HAVING place_sum > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You define alias names in the `select` clause

```
SELECT tile, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Place < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as thesum
FROM TFResults
GROUP BY tile
HAVING thesum > 1
```

Comment: Note that most RDBMS (MySQL being a notable exception) do not allow aliases to be used in `HAVING`.  In this case, you would just repeat the `CASE` expression in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just move `sum` statement to `select`:

```
SELECT
    `tile`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Place` < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS thesum 
FROM TFResults
GROUP BY `tile`
HAVING thesum > 1 ;
```